# What are the units of Optical Depth?

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

I've read several papers that describe how to calculate the Optical Depth to recombination.  They use some version of this formula:$$\tau(\eta)=\int_\eta^{\eta_*} n_e\sigma_Ta\space d\eta$$I'm trying to use this to plot the Visibility Function w/r/t redshift, but there's no mention in any document about the units.  $\sigma_T$ is generally quoted in $cm^2$.  The electron density can be $km^{-3}$, $m^{-3}$, $cm^{-3}$, there's no convention.  The product of a density and an area is going to be a $length^{-1}$.  The integral with respect to conformal time is going to be $s\space length^{-1}$.  Normally, the choice of a unit wouldn't matter, but this length is used as an exponent in the Visibility Function$$g(\eta)=\dot\tau e^{-\tau}$$and appears to be unitless.

What are the units of this function and what am I missing?

Comment: What dimension do $\eta$ and $a$ have? Also, you've made a mistake when finding dimension of the product of a density (volumetric?) and an area.

Comment: the conformal time, $\eta$, is units of seconds. $a$ - the scale factor - is unitless.  You are correct, the resultant unit of density times area is $length^{-1}$.

Comment: I suspect the source you've taken this equation from might be using units where speed of light $c=1$, and thus time and space can be assumed to have the same dimension.

Comment: I agree with your suspicion.  While they quote the formula as integrating over conformal time, I think they mean particle horizon.

Comment: [Optical depth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth) is conceptually dimensionless. Stick in a factor of $c$ to make it so.

Comment: What's wrong with a unitless parameter? Even the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_depth) states it in the opening section...

Comment: @KyleKanos - Do you know how to do a dimensional analysis on a formula?  Try it on the formula and tell me what's missing that would make it into a unitless value.

Comment: A factor of $c$ multiplying the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optical depth is usually defined in one of two ways: either as the integral over time of the scattering rate per unit time,

$$\tau = \int \Gamma_t\, dt,$$

or as the integral over distance of the scattering rate per unit distance,

$$\tau = \int \Gamma_s\, ds.$$

Since $\Gamma_t$ has dimensions of inverse time (being a number of events per unit time), and similarly $\Gamma_s$ has dimensions of inverse length, and the differentials have dimensions of time and length respectively, the optical depth is dimensionless. We can check that this makes sense by asking, for example, what an optical depth of 1 means: it means that on average you expect each photon to interact once on its path from the source to you.

Note also that, since along a light ray we have $ds = c\, dt$, the two definitions are trivially related through $\Gamma_t = c \Gamma_s$, which makes sense and is of course dimensionally consistent. So when dealing with photons it doesn't matter very much whether you integrate over time or distance, since they have a fixed speed.

The formula you quote is not the definition of $\tau$, just a formula you can use when the scattering rate has a certain expression. By dimensional analysis we have $[n_e] = L^{-3}$, $[\sigma_T] = L^2$, and $[a] = 1$, so the integrand has dimensions of inverse length. The units of conformal time depend on the definition: I've seen it defined both as $d\eta = c\, dt/a$ and as $d\eta = dt/a$; in the former case it has dimensions of length, and in the latter of time.

The thing is, in cosmology we almost always use units in which $c=1$, so the distinction doesn't matter. If we take $[\eta] = L$ then the optical depth is dimensionless and everything is fine. If we take $[\eta] = T$ then it has units of $T/L$ (inverse speed), so we just have to multiply by $c$ to make it dimensionless. The distinction of conformal time vs. particle horizon (and also of $\Gamma_t$ vs $\Gamma_s$) is not fundamental, since they're just related by a factor of $c$. They're really the same thing.

Comment: This is incorrect on several levels.  First, inverse time is not 'unitless', it's inverse time (e.g. $t^{-1}$).  Second, as nearly as I can tell, the answer is that the integration is actual over the particle horizon, not time.  If you integrate over the particle horizon, you multiply inverse length (e.g. $km^{-1}$) by a length (e.g. $km$) to get a unitless value.  The confusion comes when they assume c=1 and so freely mix the concept of conformal time with particle horizon.

Comment: @Donald when you integrate over time, you multiply by time, hence getting a unitless result; the differential has units too. And in units with $c=1$, time and space along a photon's trajectory are equal, so the integral is not wrong: it's simply what I said in my answer.

Comment: I'm confused. Electron density, $n_e$, is in units of density (e.g. $cm^{-3}$), the cross section, $\sigma_T$, is in units of area (e.g. $cm^2$) and the scale factor is unitless.  As nearly as I can tell, the units of Thompson Opacity are events per unit length (e.g. $cm^{-1}$).  Please explain how you got units of inverse time.

Comment: Also, as nearly as I can tell, the integration operation for Optical Depth (in general) is over the depth (length) of the material through which the photon passes, not the transit time.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I've expanded my answer, please tell me if it helps.

Comment: Yes.  That is a complete explanation.  Thank you.